# The puzzles of ExpiringStateSolution from Ververica Flink Training materials

Tags: apache-flink

Unfortunately, the Ververica originally training is changed and redirected to another page, that caused me unable to review the intro to this example again, I do find some other examples, but for this specific one, I failed to find it, here is something around me which I have been struggling recently,

For the core part code snippet, it is the following:
The first method for dealing with ride stream

```java
@Override
public void processElement1(TaxiRide ride, Context context, Collector<Tuple2<TaxiRide, TaxiFare>> out) throws Exception {
    TaxiFare fare = fareState.value();
    TimerService service = context.timerService();
    System.out.println("ride time service current watermark ===> " + service.currentWatermark() + "; timestamp ===>" + context.timestamp());
    System.out.println("ride state ===> " + fare);
    if (fare != null) {
        System.out.println("fare is not null ===>" + fare.rideId);
        fareState.clear();
        context.timerService().deleteEventTimeTimer(fare.getEventTime());
        out.collect(new Tuple2(ride, fare));
    } else {
        System.out.println("update ride state ===> " + ride.rideId + "===>" + context.timestamp());
        rideState.update(ride);
        System.out.println(rideState.value());
        // as soon as the watermark arrives, we can stop waiting for the corresponding fare
        context.timerService().registerEventTimeTimer(ride.getEventTime());
    }
}
```

The second method for dealing with fare stream

```java
@Override
public void processElement2(TaxiFare fare, Context context, Collector<Tuple2<TaxiRide, TaxiFare>> out) throws Exception {
    TimerService service = context.timerService();
    System.out.println("fare time service current watermark ===> " + service.currentWatermark() + "; timestamp ===>" + context.timestamp());
    TaxiRide ride = rideState.value();
    System.out.println("fare state ===> " + ride);
    if (ride != null) {
        System.out.println("ride is not null ===> " + ride.rideId);
        rideState.clear();
        context.timerService().deleteEventTimeTimer(ride.getEventTime());
        out.collect(new Tuple2(ride, fare));
    } else {
        System.out.println("update fare state ===> " + fare.rideId + "===>" + context.timestamp());
        fareState.update(fare);
        System.out.println(fareState.value() + "===>" + fareState.value().getEventTime());
        // as soon as the watermark arrives, we can stop waiting for the corresponding ride
        context.timerService().registerEventTimeTimer(fare.getEventTime());
    }
}
```

The `processElement1` is obviously for TaxiRide stream and `processElement2` is for TaxiFare,
The first thing is that it will run `processElement2` for a while before executing `processElement1`. I didn't find the reason until now, here is the print part:

```
fare time service current watermark ===> -9223372036854775808; timestamp ===>1356998400000
fare time service current watermark ===> -9223372036854775808; timestamp ===>1356998400000
fare state ===> null
fare state ===> null
update fare state ===> 26===>1356998400000
update fare state ===> 58===>1356998400000
58,2013000058,2013000058,2013-01-01 00:00:00,CRD,2.0,0.0,27.0===>1356998400000
26,2013000026,2013000026,2013-01-01 00:00:00,CRD,2.0,0.0,12.5===>1356998400000
fare time service current watermark ===> -9223372036854775808; timestamp ===>1356998400000
fare state ===> null
update fare state ===> 9===>1356998400000
fare time service current watermark ===> -9223372036854775808; timestamp ===>1356998400000
fare state ===> null
update fare state ===> 47===>1356998400000
9,2013000009,2013000009,2013-01-01 00:00:00,CRD,1.0,0.0,6.0===>1356998400000
47,2013000047,2013000047,2013-01-01 00:00:00,CRD,0.9,0.0,5.9===>1356998400000
fare time service current watermark ===> -9223372036854775808; timestamp ===>1356998400000
fare state ===> null
update fare state ===> 54===>1356998400000
fare time service current watermark ===> -9223372036854775808; timestamp ===>1356998400000
54,2013000054,2013000054,2013-01-01 00:00:00,CSH,0.0,0.0,31.0===>1356998400000
```

The second one is that,because ValueState is about one value not a list which contains a lot of values, for each call to processElemnt2, if ride is null, it will go to else, after calling fareState.update(), it will change the value of ValueState, for my perspective, it means it thinks the previous value for ValueState is match, right? -----biggest puzzle
Thx for answering that, i do appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new tutorials on [state](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/tutorials/etl.html#stateful-transformations) and [connected streams](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/tutorials/etl.html#connected-streams) should help you with your questions. But briefly:

1. You have no control over the order in which the `processElement1` and `processElement2` callbacks will be called. These two input streams are racing against each other, and the Flink runtime will do what it wants to regarding consuming events from one stream or the other. In cases where timing and/or ordering matter, you may find it necessary to buffer events in managed Flink state until your application is ready to process them.
2. ValueState is a kind of *keyed state*, which means that whenever the state is accessed or updated, the entry in the state backend *for the key in context* is read or written. The "key in context" is the key for the stream element being processed (in the case of a `processElement` callback), or for the key that created the timer (in the case of an `onTimer` callback).

Also, keep in mind that in this exercise, there is at most one TaxiRide and one TaxiFare for each key.

The reference solutions for this exercise illustrate one way of thinking about how to manage state that might otherwise leak, but this is not a situation where there is one, obviously correct answer. The purpose of this exercise is to stimulate some thinking about how to work with state and timers, and to bring some of the issues involved to the surface.

What might be our goals for a good solution? It should

- produce correct results
- not leak state
- be easy to understand
- have good performance

Now let's examine the proposed solution with these goals in mind. We find this code in `processElement1` (and by the way, `processElement2` is the same, just with the roles reversed between the ride and fare):

```java
public void processElement1(TaxiRide ride, Context context, Collector<Tuple2<TaxiRide, TaxiFare>> out) throws Exception {
    TaxiFare fare = fareState.value();
    if (fare != null) {
        fareState.clear();
        context.timerService().deleteEventTimeTimer(fare.getEventTime());
        out.collect(new Tuple2(ride, fare));
    } else {
        rideState.update(ride);
        // as soon as the watermark arrives, we can stop waiting for the corresponding fare
        context.timerService().registerEventTimeTimer(ride.getEventTime());
    }
}
```

This means that

- whenever an event arrives that does not complete a pair, we store it in state and create a timer
- whenever an event arrives that does complete a pair, we clear the state and delete the timer for the matching event (which was stored earlier)

So it's clear that nothing can leak if both events arrive. But what if one is missing?

In that case the timer will fire at some point, and run this code, which will clearly clean up any state that might exist:

```java
public void onTimer(long timestamp, OnTimerContext ctx, Collector<Tuple2<TaxiRide, TaxiFare>> out) throws Exception {
    if (fareState.value() != null) {
        ctx.output(unmatchedFares, fareState.value());
        fareState.clear();
    }
    if (rideState.value() != null) {
        ctx.output(unmatchedRides, rideState.value());
        rideState.clear();
    }
}
```

Ok, but how did we decide how long to wait? Is it enough to wait until `ride.getEventTime()`?

The effect of setting an event time timer for `ride.getEventTime()` is to wait until any out-of-orderness in the ride and fare streams has been resolved. All earlier ride and fare events will have arrived by the time the watermark reaches `ride.getEventTime()`, **assuming the watermarking is perfect**.

In these exercises, the watermarking is, in fact, perfect -- there can be no late events. But in a real-world setting, you should expect some late events, and we should expect that our implementation behaves correctly in this situation. What this reference solution will do is this:

- one of the events in a matching pair will arrive first, and create a timer to arrange for its eventual deletion
- that timer will fire, and the event will be cleared
- the matching event arrives late, and creates another timer, in this case *for a time that has already passed*
- the next arriving watermark triggers that timer, and the state is cleared

In other words, when an event is late, no state will leak, but the resulting join will not be produced. So, in cases where you want to still produce results despite late arriving data, you should create timers that will accommodate some lateness by retaining the necessary state for some additional period of time, e.g.,

```java
context.timerService().registerEventTimeTimer(ride.getEventTime() + ALLOWED_LATENESS);
```

It's not a good idea to try to accommodate arbitrarily late events, because doing so requires keeping some state for each late event indefinitely.

***What about using processing time timers instead?***

Sure, that will work, but it might be more awkward to test.

***Why not use State Time-To-Live instead?***

That's a fine idea. In general you may want to think in terms of using [State TTL](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/state/state.html#state-time-to-live-ttl) for GDPR compliance (for example), and use timers to implement business logic.

Comment: Thx for your explanation over my headache, i will study that in more depth, by the way, it seems the new training website has less examples than the original, also like this link, it's 404, it is bad user experience, when it will be available? https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master//ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/concepts/timely-stream-processing.html, it is navigated via this page https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/tutorials/streaming_analytics.html

Comment: The repo with the old examples is still at https://github.com/ververica/flink-training-exercises, and the previous version of the website was built from https://github.com/dataArtisans/flink-training/tree/gh-pages, so you can find everything there.

Comment: what you explained did break my puzzles, i really appreciate that, so detailed, right now i will go forward, Thank your time again!

Comment: You're welcome. If you would accept my answer, that would be nice.